# ¿Como puedo autoincrementar un campo alfanumerico con idendity

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE RESPONSABLE(
COD_RES     CHAR(6) INDENTITY(¿?) PRIMARY KEY,
NOM_RES     VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
APEPAT_RES  VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
APEMAT_RES  VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO RESPONSABLE VALUES('RES001', 'Pedro', 'Abanto', 'Mendoza')
SELECT * FROM RESPONSABLE 
GO
```

Comment: no puedes autoincrementar un alfanumerico

Comment: Podrías usar un campo de tipo `int` y darle formato cuando hagas la selección de la tabla.

Comment: @sstan es SQL Server. Según tengo entendido, MySQL no usa la sentencia `GO`, sino que utiliza `;` (Punto y coma). Igualmente es confuso el título con el tag.

Answer (score 3):

Es cierto lo que se ha comentado con respecto a que no se puede hacer un autoincremental con texto. Pero existe un truco que podría servirte.

1. Definir en tu tabla una columna `INT IDENTITY`
2. Agregar una **columna calculada** que sea la combinación entre un string y el `ID`:

Algo así:

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.TuTabla
       (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        COD_RES AS 'RES_' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED, 
        ......
       )
```

De esta manera, tu columna `ID`  es un `IDENTITY` normal, y  `COD_RES` tendrá valores como RES_1, RES_2, RES_3, ......, RES_50

Con la sentencia `persisted` la columna se guarda en el disco, y no es necesario calcularlo cada vez que se consulte la tabla.

**Nota**: Si utilizas mi sugerencia, tu insert sería así:

```
INSERT INTO RESPONSABLE VALUES('Pedro', 'Abanto', 'Mendoza')
```

No explicitarías el valor del Id (que es autoincremental) ni tampo del campo calculado, porque se generará automáticamente partir del texto que hayas predefinido junto con el valor del Identity.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes autoincrementar un alfanumérico, como mucho puedes crear un trigger que calcule el valor en función de un criterio predeterminado.